# MkDocs with auto generated References

Tags: python, mkdocs

I am building a TensorFlow model and have a ton of functions and modules that have proper docstrings.

I installed mkdocs due to popular demand and the documentation does appear to be very easy to write.

Nevertheless, I don't want to manually write up the entire API reference of all my modules inside this package. I am using `mkdocstrings` but I am unable to find a way to automate all of these and store them in the references section in mkdocs as you see with any documentation sites like numpy/pandas.

​

I tried [pdoc3](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/), but it only solves 1 problem for me.

[mkgendocs](https://github.com/davidenunes/mkgendocs) was something I was hoping it would work, but this requires another config file! I followed [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/easily-automate-and-never-touch-your-documentation-again-a98c91ce1b95) but it was not working for me.

​

Any suggestions/resources on how I can autogenerate all my API docstrings into an api references page in mkdocs?  Sphinx is too advanced to work with sorry. I am trying to get my team to document more so I need something easy to use and MkDocs looks like the best option currently.

Comment: Are you using this recipe: https://mkdocstrings.github.io/recipes/#automatic-code-reference-pages?

Comment: You're welcome. I wasn't completely sure what you were after, hence the question, but I put the answer below

Comment: lol I found a plugin as well right now https://github.com/AlexandreKempf/automacdoc
Neverthless I think this recipe is better as its more flexible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is described in this recipe for `mkdocstrings`:

https://mkdocstrings.github.io/recipes/#automatic-code-reference-pages